# How to print multiple lists on Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a basic recipe viewer of which i have yet to finish , a problem i have is that when i append my recipe to a list and print each list this error appears in the Python shell; the bold represent the users input

Welcome to Mohamed Ismail's Recipe Viewer

Add Recipe (add), Load Recipe (load) or Delete Recipe (delete)

**add**

Input recipe id = **1**

Input recipe name = **Cake**

Summary

---

Recipe id = 1

Recipe for Cake

Save Recipe?

**Yes**

...

Saved Succesfully

Add Recipe (add), Load Recipe (load) or Delete Recipe (delete)

**load**

Here are your existing recipe id's

Loading...

['1']

Select Recipe by id **1**

[('Recipe id =', '1')]

```
[<function function.<locals>.fileb at 0x105920400>] # this is the error
```

Go back? or exit

---

*This is my code , please help with this problem it would be much appreciated*

```
import time

currentrecipes = []
rp1 = []
rp2 = []


print("Welcome to Mohamed Ismail's Recipe Viewer")
time.sleep(1)

def function():
     print('Add Recipe (add), Load Recipe (load) or Delete Recipe (delete)')
     choice = input()
     if choice == 'add':
            a = input('Input recipe id = ')
            b = input('Input recipe name = ')
            filea = ("Recipe id =",a)
            fileb = ("Recipe for =",b)
            print('')
            print("Summary")
            print("------------------")
            file1 = print("Recipe id =",a)
            file2 = print("Recipe for",b)

            def file():
                return filea
            def fileb():
                return fileb
            file()
            fileb()
            print('Save Recipe?')
            userinput = input()
            if userinput == 'Yes':
                 if a == '1':
                    currentrecipes.append(a)
                    rp1.append(file())
                    rp2.append(fileb())
                    print('...')
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print("Saved Sucesfully")
                    function()
                 else:
                      print("Choose a recipe id of 1")
                      print("Going back...")
                      time.sleep(2)
                      function()
            else:
                 function()
     elif choice == 'load':
          if currentrecipes == []:
             print("Error 619: You have no current recipes")
             function()
          else:
             print("Here are your existing recipe id's")
             print("Loading...")
             time.sleep(2)
             print(currentrecipes)
             option = input("Select Recipe by id ")
             if option == '1':
                 print(rp1)
                 print(rp2)
                 userchoice = input("Go back? or exit ")
                 if userchoice == 'Go back':
                     function()
                 else:
                      exit()    


     elif choice == 'delete':
          if currentrecipes == []:
             print("Error 619: You have no current recipes")
             function()
          else:

              print("Here are your existing recipe id's")
              print("Loading...")
              time.sleep(2)
              print(currentrecipes)
              option = input("Which recipe do you wish to delete ")
              if option == '1':
                   if '1' not in currentrecipes:
                       print("Error 404: Recipe is not in saved recipes")
                       function()
                   else:
                       currentrecipes.remove('1')
                       print('Loading...')
                       time.sleep(1)
                       print(currentrecipes)
                       time.sleep(0.5)
                       print("Deleted Succesfully")

     else:
          print("Please select one of the 3 options")
          time.sleep(1)
          function()

function()
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you expect the output to be [('Recipe for =', 'Cake')] the problem occurs when you define the function fileb using the same name as the tuple. So, fileb() now returns a function versus the tuple you want returned.